# Please, explain みたのは

Tags: translation, meaning

> 「制服を買ってみたのは はじめてです」

In this sentence what's meaning みたのは? 
So somebody said me  that it's meaning "I have got a uniform". But I want know whe (and what is meaning) here there is みたのは？Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include what you've researched, and what you think it might be.  Otherwise you risk it being closed as a translation request.

Comment: not problem. Give me a second

Comment: You sure it's not 買ってみた?

Answer (score 2):

<テ形> みる means "try (something) and see," and in this sentence の turns the preceding verbal phrase into a noun describing the action, "the time [I] tried (doing something)". は marks this whole thing as the topic of the sentence.

It's not quite "I got a uniform," I don't think, but that's the gist of it; I might say "This is the first time I tried to buy a uniform."

Answer (score 0):

It's probably 買ってみた and not 買て since て-form of 買う is 買って.

> **[制服を買ってみた] のは [はじめて] です** 
>   • 制服: Seifuku (school uniform)
>   • 買う: Kau (to buy)
>   • 買ってみた：Tried things then bought it. みた is the past form of 見る。
>   *-> Formula (V-て) + みる(look) : Do something in order to see what will happens / see the result of it (Try)*
>   • のは is particle. The の package *[Try uniform and bought it]* as a noun, and は marks it as a topic. 
>   • はじめて：Hajimete (The first time)

So it literally means: 
*About [Trying school uniform and then bought it], this is [the first time].* 
Natural translation: 
*It is my first time to tried and bought a school uniform.*

CMWII

Comment: I don't think "try before buying it" is quite right. My understanding of this construction is the combo (do something) and see, which gives natural translation more like: "This is the first time I tried buying a school uniform"

Comment: `Tried something in order to bought it` -> If you meant to type "Tried something on in order to buy it" then it'd be like 「買うために試着した」「買うために着てみた」, etc.  「Formula(V-て)+みる」 would usually  be more like "try doing ~" (rather than "try to do")

Comment: @chocolate You are correct, it is not 'Try in order to do things'. But just simply 'Try'. I've update the answer.Thanks.